# Create a list of WebElements in Selenium using Class Name

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a class on a webpage i am trying to create automated tests for, which is used several times, is there anyway to create a list of each of these in java so i can use them later?

```
<LABEL onclick="doSomeThing();" id=smainMenu1 title="Program JSP001" class=node>Link1</LABEL>
<LABEL onclick="doSomeThing();" id=smainMenu2 title="Program JSP002" class=node>Link2</LABEL>
<LABEL onclick="doSomeThing();" id=smainMenu3 title="Program JSP003" class=node>Link3</LABEL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findElements` (in plural)

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("node"));
```